How do I convince my boss to use an up to date version of software to develop a new SaaS
So I've been tasked to develop a SaaS. Originally it was to be an internal tool, but during the design phase I was asked to make it multitenant capable (for external companies to use).
The problem
The system was asked to be built using an older codebase (ruby/rails). The language version on the server I am allowed to deploy on is already 1 year out of LTS (Long Term Support) and the framework version two years out of LTS. This is before development even started.
I asked about building using the latest versions or at least one that wasn't out of LTS, but was told this is the only server we can put it on so the versions were set. As an internal tool, I begrudgingly accepted that it is what it is.
Now after being told to add multitenant functionality, I approached it again. I was told this is the codebase and version I need to build it on.
I start diving into the existing codebase that I am to build upon. It is a simple setup with a few unwanted bits but it includes an email f2p setup and IP restriction features. The code itself is a mess. I asked the original developer and I was told this felt more like a "learn the framework, learn the language" project when it was originally created. (last update to the codebase is also 2 years ago).
note: the company has money, but I am not in a position to know any details so I can only accept it if they say "we don't have the money". -- though it would be highly suspect
The question
I need to make a convincing case to my boss why we have to use a newer version of the language/framework and preferably rebuild from scratch, regardless of my boss stating that the server mentioned is the only place we can host it.
What I have so far

The system is employing additional security (2fa, ip restriction), so security is of concern

using software out of LTS opens the SaaS to both known and unknown security holes that will not be patched (more impactful if I find specific examples of existing and unpatched security holes)
our company supposedly is compliant with a number of security certifications (I cannot fathom using out of LTS frameworks as being compliant)


the existing codebase is small enough it would be less costly to rebuild it than to spend the time refactoring

cleaning up coding from someone learning the language/framework as they built it
handling the differences in design between the purpose of the original code base and the current SaaS product being built
not having to handle the learning curve of figuring out the existing code (leading to refactoring needs or perpetuating poor coding practices)


using an old version at the start adds considerable technical debt to a product that has barely left the design stage and will only get worse before it is released (save a little now only to spend a considerable sum later)

Are there any other points (in addition or new) that I can use to make my case?

Additional aside
I am actively looking for a new job and have been interviewing. If I'm lucky I will find a good job before I get too far down this rabbit hole and I won't have to deal with these issues immediately. Though in web services this is an unfortunate and common problem, so I feel it is still worth finding an answer because I am certain this same problem will crop up sooner than later again.
(so please don't suggest "quitting" ;))

"Though in web services this is an unfortunate and common problem" I have been developing "web services" since before they were called web services and I never had this problem. Not the absolute latest bleeding edge? Sure. Version updates during development? Sure. Out of support before the project even started? Never.

Just be aware that everyone always thinks that "the existing codebase is small enough it would be less costly to rebuild it than to spend the time refactoring ". Apart from the people who think "the existing codebase is too big to refactor, it would be quicker to rebuild it"

Truthfully, sometimes we (meaning me and my colleagues) are hesistant to always use the latest version of software particularly because it could prone to bugs. Developing software isn't easy. Many times you inadvertently create more issues than you resolve.

Ruby on Rails has reasonable version upgrade support, in that the version update process is broadly documented, and support can be found online with walk-throughs and tutorials etc. This might help as an alternative to rebuild on this project - unless the existing project is very small, it will probably be less effort overall, and can be done in stages. You also don't have to get to bleeding edge current versions, just within the LTS windows for Ruby and Rails.

I routinely suggest the “n-1” version of a LTS project. These LTS versions are out of support it you don’t indicate if they support everything you need to complete the project. The only “security certifications” I am aware that exist practically have no requirements with regards to using LTS software, so I would be interested, in understanding which ones your referring to.

The language of your manager is "money", not "outdated" or "newest". So take the version already on the server and the newest, compare them side by side, make a list of the important differences. Features updated, features added, security problems fixed. Explain what will NOT be available in the SaaS product if using the outdated software.
If the info is available, show what happened with other companies which used the same outdated version. The more expensive the damage, the better.
However, at the end of the day, it is the job of the management to make decisions, and our job as employees to follow them. Or to find another job :)

[EDIT]
You mentioned "Japan" in a comment. Please remember that the Japanese government is still using floppy disks - and just started making efforts to phase them out. So using stuff which is too old might be the way of living in those parts of the world.

https://www.reuters.com/world/asia-pacific/japan-declares-victory-effort-end-government-use-floppy-disks-2024-07-03/

Floppy drives, it isn’t broke, it doesn’t have to be fixed. If you have no need to transfer files larger than 1.44MB they make sense. Engineers have a habit of over engineering solutions, I am certainly guilty of that, while simultaneously working with hardware that is 55 years old. Sometimes the money doesn’t exist to replace something that works. It not being shiny isn’t a reason to update it

@MiniRagnarok: so they kind of succeeded, expect in the areas where they did not :))

@Donald: The big problem with floppy disks is not that they do not work when they work, it is that they can lose data quite easily.I remember how often i had to replace floppies exactly because of that. In today's world, the electromagnetism is even more of a problem than 20 years ago, so for the data that really needs to be available... Not no mention the chaos and hard work - when needed to find a certain file which surely must exist on one of those 5000 floppies... :) They were phased out for a very good reason. Same as CDs and DVDs... And let's not forget the physical space needed for them

@Donald: I read again your comment: they used the floppies for storing (read "archiving"), not for casual transferring. And it was the government of Japan, not a kindergarden in a poor village on a no-name island, or the office of a nostalgic geek :) I even consider myself building an old computer for running DOS games, at that computer would be unfinished without floppy drives... And additionally - the pride of using 3D-printed "Save" icons... :)

@virolino - I am personally aware that the DoD still uses floppies and they have multiple billion dollar budgets. Sometimes the simplest solution is the solution. It really has nothing to do who is using out dated solution. I shared my knowledge for a reason you did. The point it will be difficult to change individuals mind, if the current solution works, and they have a history of getting new technology that doesn’t work. Guess how I know about new technology not working?

@Donald: Please do tell HOW you know and WHAT you know... :) just do not let us here boil without the juice :) I also know that in very important systems, they still use computers like 386's simply because it does the job excellently without problems - and thus, without need for improvement. They could replace the 386's with i9's, but for no added benefit, and for increased risks.

@virolino - I little bald eagle might have told me.  In other news, I agree with your answer; I can't tell you how many 50-year-old systems that simply work, end up being replaced with newer systems that don't work. Yes, it was difficult to diagnose the 50-year-old system, but for the individuals who learned the system it wasn't that difficult.

You can try to collect some coherent "business" arguments to convince the powers at be. Examples could be

There is considerable legal exposure. If there is a vulnerability in the old framework and a customer gets hacked, you maybe found "grossly negligent" by starting the development on a out of date unsupported platform
Continuing the "hacked" use case: It would be very difficult and expensive to fix any vulnerability since you have to do it all yourself inside a potentially huge and complicated code base.
The product might hard to sell. These days it would be VERY hard to sell software that runs on Windows 10 and NOT not Windows 11
The product might be not be competitive. Competitive products may offer features that customers expect, but that would be difficult, costly or even impossible to implement on the old framework.
Difficult to future proof. Even if you have feature parity right now, the new frameworks will evolve and so will features and customer expectations. It will be costly to keep up.

Technical debt costs real money. Starting a new project with a huge technical debt from day 1 doesn't make business sense.

Explaining to non-tech managers can be painful. The key is not to try to teach them or expect to learn the tech. If you reach into the "Business World" logic it isn't usually difficult to get a reasonable person to agree with you.
Business reponses must address:

How does it increase sales
How does it reduce cost
How does it reduce risk

"It is a good idea" is not on the list.
Frame the logic in business verbiage.

The greater security of using "In Life" tools will make this product more saleable (increase sales).
Using tools that are "In Life / Currently Supported" will reduce our support costs.
Starting with "Tech Debt" will likely increase costs and decrease pool of future available coders
Unable to be SOC Compliant (or other security certification)

Make your points in this style to have business impact.

On the "reduce risk" part, add the fact that many out of date web development languages have huge security holes in them. It can help to list all the security updates that have happened since that version was released. Point to how data has been stolen or web systems brought down due to such security holes.

Does your company have a competent CISO? If yes, he/she would be the one to define polices regarding the use of outdated/unsupported development tools and libraries. If there are such policies, check whether they support your case. If yes, you have a very good argument to present to your manager. Otherwise, this might be an opportunity to suggest changes in the security policy to deal with this situation.

I'll try digging into the compliance rules. To my knowledge there is no CISO at the company. It's a common problem in Japan -- companies are big on compliance, but rarely have an actual IT security team (usually the 'security team' is compliance heavy and consists of employees without security certifications)

I think you're missing the point.
The real problem is that the hierarchy does not trust you. If they did, you'd get a free hand to build from the bottom up. You could build a webserver in a couple of days or less. Or chuck a virtual machine into an existing server. You have asked twice and pointed out importance etc,. and both times been fobbed off with no leverage to get your way.
Asking a third time isn't going to increase their trust levels. You're already job hunting, just keep at it. Another option is just to go ahead and build it however you want it. What are they going to do?
The time to hit back was the first time you were denied.

The trust issue might be personal, might be based on a perceived notion of inexperience, or might not have anything to do with the individual itself. However, I agree, the trust relationship doesn’t exist. How the author builds that trust relationship will likely depend on the reasons it doesn’t exist

@Donald one way to do that is to take ownership and get the project done without bugging the manager about servers he knows little about.

Security should match with the level of possible damage
The first and most important question to ask in these scenarios is how much damage would there be if a security breach happens and the system is totally compromised? The cost to mitigate should not exceed the cost of damages.  Think of it like spending $1,000 on security measures to protect a piece of jewelry worth $10.
For your scenario does the possible damage of a compromise exceed the cost of a new server and several years of software development effort?
If yes then:
Make the problem your boss' problem
People are much more likely to care about a problem if said problem impacts them directly.  An apocryphal story that has been passed down:
There was a meeting where a new internal timekeeping software for the company was being demoed to executives.  The executives were impressed and want it to be pushed out company wide as soon as possible.  One engineer protested this stating that it had security vulnerabilities that needed to be addressed.  The executive in charge was dismissive to the concerns, so the engineer went over to where the new timekeeping site was being demoed.  They then proceeded to use an exploit to log in as the executive in charge of the meeting showing the executive's timesheet to everyone in the meeting.
Suddenly the executive had a change of heart and demanded that the security vulnerabilities be fixed as soon as possible and that this would not be allowed to go out until it had been fixed.
I cannot recommend the kind of action above since that can easily backfire or at the very least be a career limiting move.  However, if you can frame or show this issue in a way where it is no longer just a security problem, but something that will directly cause harm to those in charge, then they will be more likely to act upon it.
Though be warned sometimes how leadership deals with problems is to get rid of the person reporting the problem rather than addressing the problem.
